# What is the difference with tables and their subtables in setting them to nil in Lua?

Tags: lua

I know that Lua retains a table in memory for as long as there remains a reference to it somewhere in the code, which means that you cannot set tables to nil by passing them to functions as arguments. However, I do not understand why you can do this to subtables.

```lua
local a = {}
a.b = {}

local function remove( t )
    t.b = nil
    t = nil
end

remove( a )

print( a and a.b, a )
```

After passing **a** as an argument to function **remove**, I set the argument and its subtable to nil. I know that this should not set **a** to nil due to the aforementioned reasons, but can someone enlighten me as to why **a.b** can be set to nil, even though, to my understanding, it should still have a reference to it from the outside, just like with **a**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that Lua retains a table in memory for as long as there remains a reference to it somewhere in the code,

Yes, but all this really means is that we don't have to worry about memory management. We don't normally ever think about when tables get garbage collected unless we're really tight on memory and have to tweak the garbage collector. For normal usage, we can assume that a table is deleted from memory as soon as we lose our last reference to it.

> which means that you cannot set tables to nil by passing them to functions as arguments.

That's not really the reason. A table and nil are two different data types, so you can't literally set a table to nil. Usually what we mean by "setting a table to nil" is to take a variable or table key that refers to a table, and set that variable/key to nil. That may or may not be our last remaining reference to that table.

The reason a function can't set an argument variable is because a parameter (local to the function) and a variable used as an argument are two entirely different variables.

> but can someone enlighten me as to why a.b can be set to nil, even though, to my understanding, it should still have a reference to it from the outside, just like with a.

No, the table `a.b` does not have an outside reference. There are no local variables that reference that table. Table keys do not have scope the way variables do. The only reference to that table is inside table `a`, which gets modified by the statement `t.b = nil`.

The statement `t.b = nil` works because it modifies the *table* `t`, which more than one variable refers to. 't = nil' assigns to the *variable* `t`, which is essentially unrelated to any other variable.

Comment: Good explanation.  "Variables used as an argument": Yes, an argument is an expression. An expression that is a variable is a specific case but not special at all. The caller is passed the value of the expression.  It would have no knowledge of where the value came from.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you're not "setting `a.b` to `nil`". A precise way to describe what `t.bil = nil` does is

"associating the value `nil` with the key `"b"` in table `a`"

For example, compare what you have written to the following:

```lua
local o = {}
o[1] = "one"
o[2] = "two"
o[3] = "three"

-- o currently looks like
--  KEY | VALUE
-- -----+--------
--    1 | "one"
--    2 | "two"
--    3 | "three"


o[2] = nil

-- o now looks like
--  KEY | VALUE
-- -----+--------
--    1 | "one"
--    3 | "three"
```

This very clearly is not "setting the number `2` to nil". This is merely modifying the *contents* of the table `o` to no longer associated the key `2` with any value.

Looking back at code more like you originally asked about:

```lua
local alpha = {}
local beta = {}

alpha[1] = "one"
alpha[2] = beta
alpha[3] = "three"

-- alpha now looks like
--  KEY | VALUE
-- -----+--------
--    1 | "one"
--    2 | <beta>
--    3 | "three"

alpha[2] = nil

-- alpha now looks like
--  KEY | VALUE
-- -----+--------
--    1 | "one"
--    3 | "three"
```

Again, `beta` is not modified in any way, and neither is the number `2`. Merely, the association of `2` with the value `beta` has been removed from the contents of table `alpha`.

Comment: In your code,

`local beta = {}; 
alpha[2] = beta; 
alpha[2] = nil;` 

this sets the reference to beta nil, but doesn't actually set beta, the table, to nil. I get this.

In my code, however, since subtable a.b is assigned nil value and it is no longer accessible, then isn't it the same as nil and won't it be garbage collected? Or will it stay as a part of the table, but in a non-accessible way, until the table that it is a part of is finally properly set to nil?

Comment: Your code is exactly like this. `.b` is just like `[2]`.

Comment: `a.b` in your initial code is not some special "home" for the table. There's implicitly a "local" variable created to hold `{}`, and then that local variable is put into the key `b` in `a`, just as shown here.